# How would the general public be kept unaware of a zombie outbreak?

Tags: internal-consistency, science-fiction, post-apocalypse, apocalypse

Consider a zombie outbreak beginning in March 2020 rather than the Covid-19 pandemic we have today.

This pandemic has started intentionally by a secret world organization to lower down the human population to less than 100 million people worldwide.

But the thing is they want this to go down with as minimum panic as possible. Obviously, there'll be panic when this reaches to a certain extent but it should start at the late phases of the pandemic when it'll be impossible to take action in cities with large crowds.

These Zombies are still humans, they can think, run and hide. They don't only need to bite to spread the infection, they can also scratch or beat you.  They aren't as stupid as traditional zombies and they scavenge for resources (Water, shelter...). However, they're unable to speak, or but they can show emotions (Like they're unwilling to murder but they can't contain the urge). They're just hungry and angry.

With modern technology and media, how would this pandemic be kept a rumor so that it could spread rapidly before people start noticing it in masses?

Comment: What compulsions / needs do the zombies have that make them a threat rather than suddenly mute humans?  How is the pandemic starting (people and places) - very different having a disease that can spread without initial symptoms vs something that must be the result of a physical assault?

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Think of them as normal zombies. They just want to spread the infection as much as possible and they want to keep the host alive. They don't really make the host mute. There're couple ways to spread the infection, one of it is obviously by biting. I just want to capture the last days of the modern civilization before people are aware that things won't be the same again. But to do that I need people to continue about their lives and be unaware that people somewhere else are dying-fast. I need about a week before shit hits the fan and want to focus on that week alone.

Comment: "They just want to spread the infection as much as possible and they want to keep the host alive."  Does this mean that the virus is a sapient and/or hive mind intelligence directing the actions of the hosts?  Also, still need to know initial number and distribution of infection points and delay from infection to symptoms.

Comment: Why do you assume that panic is inevitable? And what do you mean when you say 'panic'?

Answer (score 5):

Zombies!?! What kind of stupid sheeple believe those lies. It's obviously the deep state trying to control us by making us wear "protective" things to take away our freeeeeedom. Those sheep masks and chip filled, poisonous vaccines that track us and make people turn all liberal-like are really what's causing a few people to have trouble speaking. Most of the zombies in films are just crisis actors. I saw a video on YouTube showing an empty ward in a hospital somewhere and it was supposed to be a zombie ward, and that just proves again that there ain't no zombies. There was also this doctor or professor or something like that on the TrueRealFactualNews website saying that the Lizard People helped the libs with staging the whole thing and he even waved a great big pile of papers that he said had absolute proof on them. Bill Gates is just using this to turn us into slaves on his potato farms and distract us from realizing that true American elections are decided by who has the most flags on their pickup trucks. Even if zombie disease is real, some doctor who got fired and lost his license just for telling the truth posted pictures on FaceBook saying that a couple spoonfuls of sheep dewormer for a few days is all that's needed to prevent it or or treat it or something.

Comment: hmmmm. Where have I heard this before?

Answer (score 2):

Scapegoats. They aren't zombies their Antifa or white supremacists or something else. People already believe that zombies aren't real so they're more likely to take another explanation no matter how unlikely that explanation is.   These zombies aren't stupid. They'll most likely try and hide evidence at least at first.  This will be made easier if they can still communicate and coordinate with other zombies.  This also gives them a reason to spread the infection.

Answer (score 2):

**Social media and control over the news**

Due to the lack of information readily available or shared by some countries with regards to the virus' impact, paired with said countries having almost full control over social media and news agencies, it may well be relatively easy to make a case for a conspiracy cover up.

I'd assume that such a cover up would be short-lived: eventually the truth would come out, as discrepancies would slowly but steadily pile up. It just takes a few individuals being able to share photos and/or footage for the cover up to collapse.

**Heavy military operations and propaganda**

That said, it may well be impossible for a cover up to work: we are not talking about a flu-like pandemic with 5-20% death rate, we are talking of a full-blown zombie apocalypse with all that entails. Control over social media  and news agencies wouldn't be enough: the military should be involved. Blacked out containment zones, with heavy logistics and even heavier propaganda to keep those that know about it quiet. In movies, soldiers seem to blindly obey orders to contain people within "black zones" during a zombie outbreak. In reality, I struggle to believe that they would follow those orders: it may well be that some have families and/or friends within those zones, or that they would have empathy towards the condemned.

I do not want to turn this at all into a political debate of any kind, I'm just pointing out the fact that the more control a single entity/organisation has over its population's ability to share information, the more chances of success for a cover up there are. And the more virulent/lethal the outbreak, the harder that would be to achieve, or the more extreme the measures to be taken would be.

Comment: Thanks. This is a genuine answer. I also do think it's impossible to keep the news as a rumor for a long time, the truth would eventually come out. But it would still delay the panic as much as possible.